# I'm getting EOF while looking for matching `"'

Tags: bash, shell

this is a bash script. im getting the error in the if statement line

```
# 2. read a line of input from the keyboard
   read answer

    if [-z "$answer"]
    then
        $answer=$default
    else
        $default=$answer
    fi
```

i don't do much bash anymore, i can't see the error, ive tried

```
if [-z "$answer"]; then
```

and that failed as well with the same error.  can anyone else see the error?

**EDIT UPDATE**
i changed it to this

```
read answer

        if [ -z "$answer" ]
        then
            $answer=$defaultEntry
        else
            $defaultEntry=$answer
        fi
```

and the same error occures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply leave spaces between the brackets and condition:

```
if [ -z "$answer" ]
```

Comment: this worked, i was also missing a quote further up the script

Answer (score 0):

There should be a space between `[` and `-z`, and between `"` and `]`.

`[` is an alias to the `test` program.

`[` is a program, which bash can execute.

`[-z` isn't, thus an error.

Answer (score 0):

You need spaces around `[` and `]`. E.g.:

```
if [ -z "$answer" ]
then
    $answer=$default
else
    $default=$answer
fi
```

The reason for this is that `[` is actually a shell builtin command.

```
[me@home]$ type [
[ is a shell builtin
[me@home]$ which [
/usr/bin/[
```

If you omit the space after `[`, you're mangling the command name into something that does not exist.

```
[me@home]$ [ -z "something" ] # OK. calling command [ with some args
[me@home]$ [-z "something" ]  # fail. calling command [-z with some args
-bash: [-z: command not found
```

The `[` command also checks that the last argument is `]`, therefore if you don't have spaces around that it becomes part of the previous argument and the `[` command will complain:

```
[me@home]$ [ -z "something" ]  # this runs fine becuase last arg is ]
[me@home]$ [ -z "something"]  # will fail. last arg is "something"]
-bash: [: missing `]'
```

Answer (score 0):

The space around the `[` and `]` is important, as others have pointed out.

Also, you should not be using `$` when assigning to a variable.

Try this:

```
read answer

if [ -z "$answer" ]
then
    answer=$defaultEntry
else
    defaultEntry=$answer
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
read answer

if [ -z "$answer" ]    #Spaces!
then
    answer=$default    # Use "answer" and not "$answer"
else
    default=$answer    # Use "default" and not "$default"
fi
```

This now works except that I don't have a value for $default. I suspect you've done that elsewhere (as well as set a prompt).